# Specify MSVC version for bazel

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, bazel

I'm looking for a way to tell bazel which version of VC++ it should use.
I have already set `BAZEL_VC=\VS2017Community\VC\`
but the problem is my directory `\VS2017Community\VC\Tools\MSVC` has a number of different VC++ compilers. In particular the following versions are there

```
14.11.25503
14.13.26020
14.15.26726
14.16.27023
```

It is possible to force bazel to use specific version? By default it uses the first one(in alphabetic order) which is incorrect for me.

Comment: There are an eye-watering large number of github issues, none however that seem to address this issue.  You could try including the subdirectory in the BAZEL_VC value.  If that doesn't help then consider that a clean VS2017 install only has the 27023 subdir, so you could just move or delete the agile shrapnel.  If that doesn't help then use the github issues site to get advice.

Comment: Yes of course, renaming works fine but it's not a solution.

Comment: I gave you 3 solutions, I can't help you when you shoot down the one I didn't even mention.  Use github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no official way to do it.
This is how bazel search for MSVC compiler (from Visual Studio 2017)

```
# Normally there should be only one child directory under %VC_PATH%\TOOLS\MSVC,
# but iterate every directory to be more robust.
for path in dirs:
    tool_path = str(path) + "\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\" + tool
    if repository_ctx.path(tool_path).exists:
        break
```

Basically, it will get first found directory with `cl.exe`

One workaround could be just to rename/move all subdirs you don't need and left necessary one untouched.
The true way is to change source code and recompile bazel :)

Answer (score 2):

Bazel now reads `BAZEL_VC_FULL_VERSION`, set in addition to `BAZEL_VC`.

```
set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC
set BAZEL_VC_FULL_VERSION=14.16.27023
```

This was added for Visual Studio 2017 and 2019. Older VS versions don't support it.

[Source: Bazel Windows documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html#build-c-with-msvc)